# Pandas - create a new excel file by combining common keys from two excel files

Tags: python, pandas

I have taken the contents of two excel files in data frames  **df1** and **df2** respectively. I want to create a new excel file which will contain only the **common headers** from file 1 and file 2 but values has to be only from file 2. For example: File 1 has headers a,b,c,d and file 2 has headers a,c.
The new excel file will have only headers a and c but values will only be **from file 2 and not file 1**.
How can I achieve this in pandas. I tried merge function but its not giving me the desired result.

Comment: Can you post some code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Some code *and* data would be useful to understand your problem. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Does `df2[df2.columns.intersection(df1.columns)]` give you what you're after? (or maybe `df2.to_excel('filename.xlsx', columns=df2.columns.intersection(df1.columns))` might be more suitable

Comment: your approach please

Answer (score 0):

You can get the intersection of the columns using `np.intersect1d` and then apply this to `df2`.

```
Colmask = np.intersect1d(np.array(df1.columns), np.array(df2.columns))
df2[Colmask]
```

A more idiomatic way would be:

```
df2[df2.columns.intersection(df1.columns)]
```